# How to create a selector tool with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, selector

I am looking to create a dog breed selector tool where users can narrow down dog breeds by selecting certain characteristics. This is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#big,#long").click(function(){
  $("#pug").hide();
  });
    $("#small,#long").click(function(){
  $("#bull").hide();
  });
    $("#big,#short").click(function(){
  $("#pom").hide();
  });
    $("#small,#short").click(function(){
  $("#new").hide();
  });
});
</script>
<p>Size</p>
<button id="small">Small</button>
<button id="big">Big</button>
<p>Coat</p> 
<button id="short">Short Hair</button>
<button id="long">Long Hair</button>
<p id="pug">Pug</p>
<p id="bull">Bulldog</p>
<p id="pom">Pomeranian</p>
<p id="new">Newfoundland</p>
```

I've tried incorporating .show() in order to get the breeds to reappear after another characteristic is reselected, but then all of the breeds reappear which defeats the purpose of the tool.

I know a little php, so let me know if it would be easer using it instead.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to combine them? For example clicking `small` AND `long` will hide `#bull`?

Comment: at the moment when you click on a button, something hides, do you want to show what is hidden after you click the same button again?

Comment: @BenM I want #bull to hide when either small or long (or both) are selected.

Comment: @aurel toggling dog breeds is an option, but my goal is to be able to hide a breed when its characteristics are not selected, and display its characteristics when they are.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if you just added the specific class to the name ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/gmHTN/2/)):

```
<p id="pug" class="small short">Pug</p>
<p id="bull" class="big short">Bulldog</p>
<p id="pom" class="small long">Pomeranian</p>
<p id="new" class="big long">Newfoundland</p>
```

Then you can use this code:

```
$(function () {
    var size = '',
        coat = '',
        $list = $('#list'),
        selectType = function () {
            $list.find('p').hide();
            $list.find('p' + size + coat).show();
        };

    $("#big,#small").click(function() {
        size = '.' + this.id;
        $('#big').toggleClass('selected', this.id === "big");
        $('#small').toggleClass('selected', this.id === "small");
        selectType();
    });
    $("#short,#long").click(function () {
        coat = '.' + this.id;
        $('#short').toggleClass('selected', this.id === "short");
        $('#long').toggleClass('selected', this.id === "long");
        selectType();
    });

});
```

---

Opps, updated the code to work properly and color the selected button.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. The code above looks great and accomplishes what I was looking for. Ultimately, I would like to add additional breed characteristics such as temperament, trainability, etc. Will the code pattern above permit me to reach that end, or will I have to take another approach?

Comment: Yes, just follow that pattern and add the new name to the end... `$list.find('p' + size + coat + stat1 + stat2).show();`

Comment: I just did that, and it works great except that the button color remain blue after the first click. Is there a way for the color to toggle along with the values?